# Changes made in the gitlab.yml are not reflecting after running the "gitlab-ctl reconfigure" command

Tags: gitlab

While I am configuring LDAP with GitLab,I have made the changes in gitlab.yml file which is in `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc==>gitlab.yml`. But after running the "gitlab-ctl reconfigure" command in the terminal,the changes made to "gitlab.yml" file are not reflecting.

The changes I made to `gitlab.yml` file are :

```
host: '172.16.3.25'
port: 389
uid: 'uid'
method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
bind_dn: 'user'
password: 'user'allow_username_or_email_login: true
base: 'ou=people,dc=thbs,dc=com’
active_directory: false
```

Comment: Take a look at the line starting with the word `password`, it looks like you joined 2 lines, try separating them and running the command again, also try and take a look at the error logs (Should be something like `sudo gitlab-ctl tail`)

Comment: Added as an official answer, feel free to vote and mark as correct answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a misconfiguration due to syntax error.

Try separating this:

```
password: 'user'allow_username_or_email_login: true
```

To this:

```
password: 'user'
allow_username_or_email_login: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you :)

The issue got resolved.

After changing the configuration in gitlab.yml file :::

host: '172.16.3.25'
port: 389
uid: 'uid'
method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
bind_dn: 'user'
password: 'user'
allow_username_or_email_login: true
base: 'ou=people,dc=thbs,dc=com’
active_directory: false

We have to restart the gitlab.To restart use the below command:

sudo service gitlab restart

Then it will work.